# why i am getting this error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404, my api is ok in postman, but when i try in front i go er

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, axios

when I send a request in the front I get error of uncaught in (promise) request failed with status 404
it was working but when  I put other function function in the same page like login or get user ou update, I started to get this error

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
```

```
export default function Formulario() {
  const [username,setUsername] = useState("")

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await axios("/users/register", {
      username,
    });
    
      console.log(res)
    
  };
```

```
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label> Username</label>
      <input type="text"
      onChange={(e) =>setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    )
}
```

*this is the api*

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
```

````
// postando username

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username
        });

        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);


    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
        
module.exports = router
```
````

Comment: I PUT POST IN {(      await axios.post(/users/register, )} and still the same problem

Comment: Did you check the network tab of your browser devtools? Where does the request go? Is the url displayed correct?

Comment: Your handleSubmit function is making a GET request to "/users/register" and your API exposes a POST route on "/register". Either you are not providing the full code or you need to fix your paths and methods.

Comment: i type de code wrong i forgot to type ** post ** in   const res= await axios.post ("/users/register,       by the way i continue with the same problem the console.log show post method and uncaught promise

Answer (score 0):

By, the looks of it, I think your axios instance is not making the react to a valid url. Unless your have the `baseUrl` property set on your axios

1. Check the browser's network tab to see if your app (react) is making a request to the correct endpoint (same as postman endpoint).